# Building a combined encryption scheme from two encryption schemes that's secure if at least on of them is secure

Tags: encryption, provable-security, chosen-plaintext-attack

Any thoughts on how this can be done?

> Let $\Pi_1 = (\mathrm{Gen}_1, \mathrm{Enc}_1, \mathrm{Dec}_1)$ and $\Pi_2 = (\mathrm{Gen}_2, \mathrm{Enc}_2, \mathrm{Dec}_2)$ be two encryption schemes for which it is known that at least one is CPA-secure. The problem is that you don't know which one is CPA-secure and which one may not be. Show how to construct an encryption scheme $\Pi$ that is guaranteed to be CPA-secure as long as at least one of $\Pi_1$ or $\Pi_2$ is CPA-secure.

*[Problem 3.21 - Jonathan Katz, Yehuda Lindell - Introduction to Modern Cryptography: Principles and Protocols](https://books.google.de/books?id=5ebKBQAAQBAJ&pg=PA109&lpg=PA109&dq=%22from+the+original+plaintext+so+that+knowledge%22).*

Comment: Related question: [On composition of encryption schemes](https://crypto.stackexchange.com/questions/25710/on-composition-of-encryption-schemes) (same OP)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

You can generate a random string $s_1$ as long as the plaintext. Then XOR this value with the plaintext generating $s_2$. Now encrypt both parts using $\mathrm{Enc}_1$ and $\mathrm{Enc}_2$. You need to decrypt both to XOR the two parts together again. This is similar to secret sharing where you need two parts of a key to decrypt.

If $\mathrm{Gen}_1$ and $\mathrm{Gen}_2$ are two random generators then you may want to XOR those together as well when generating $s_1$. I presume however that they are used to generate the secret keys.

Comment: While this certainly is valid, and matches the hint given in the [question before it vanished](http://crypto.stackexchange.com/revisions/25733/6), I do not see anything wrong with cascaded encryption (using independent keys), which does not depend on a random generator, and has shorter ciphertext.

Comment: Gen is clearly the key generation algorithm. Mathematically encryption is often modeled as a tuple of three algorithms, key generation, encryption and decryption. The combined scheme will invoke the two individual key generation algorithms in its key generation algorithm, using the tuple/concatenation of the two individual keys as its key.

Comment: Ok all seems well now. @fgrieu I would happily upvote another answer. This one is indeed more complex than strictly necessary.

Comment: @fgrieu : $\:$ The inner scheme could be such that the lengths of its ciphertexts noticeably depend on their corresponding plaintexts, and the outer scheme could be CPA-secure but still such that its ciphertexts reveal enough about the lengths of their corresponding plaintexts. $\;\;\;\;$

Comment: @MaartenBodewes : $\:$ You're missing the point: In the case I described, the cascade $\hspace{1.13 in}$ would _not_ be CPA-secure, even though one of the schemes would be CPA-secure. $\hspace{1.39 in}$

Comment: @Ricky Demer: indeed if the first and non-CPA-secure encryption scheme causes an expansion of 1000 bytes for plaintext that starts with the string "fubar", cascaded encryption is insecure, but the answer gives a CPA-secure scheme. Good catch; I will remember considering leaks by size in questions on cascaded encryption.